# Which DIY recipes can you "self-learn"?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

An overwhelmingly vast majority of DIY recipes in the game can be found by buying them from Nook's Cranny, finding them in the balloon presents or beach bottles, or getting them from crafting villagers. However, there's a couple recipes that you "self-learn" after you've fulfilled certain conditions. For example, after digging up my first manila clam, I automatically learned how to craft fish bait. Or after catching a second boot while fishing, I learned the recycled boots recipe. What other self-learned DIY recipes are available, and what triggers your character to learn them?

Comment: I think it might just be the bait, the trash recycling, and the Bunny Day egg outfits.

Comment: [Golden tool recipes](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Golden_tools#New_Horizons) are all learned after completing varying numbers of tasks.  The recipe for a pitfall can also be learned by digging up a pitfall.

Comment: Man, those sound like good answers... *cough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These recipes can be learned by yourself:

- **Tire Toy**: Fish up a tire
- **Tire Stack**: Fish up several tires
- **Succulent Plant**: Fish up one Empty Can
- **Recycled-can Thumb Piano**: Fish up Empty Cans
- **Trash Bags**: Fish up several Trash items
- **Garbage-heap Wall**: Fish up all different Trash items
- **Garbage-heap Flooring**: Fish up all different Trash items
- **Recycled Boots**: Fish up Boots
- **Fish Bait**: Dig up a Manila Clam
- (**Medicine:** Talk to a villager after getting stung)